# How to generate a custom image of CentOS for MAAS

Tags: maas

I want to generate a custom image of CentOS containing desired tools and packages (such as QT framework, PostgreSQL and several other packages) for deploying it to the nodes of MAAS.

Please suggest any procedure to build the custom CentOS image with desired packages installed within it.

Comment: Questions on CentOS should be asked on [unix.se].

Comment: Actually, the question is related to MAAS, which supports CentOS images also.

Comment: Related, but the images are for CentOS.

Comment: MAAS supports creation of custom images for several OS including CentOS

Comment: So we should support "several OS including CentOS"?

Comment: I mean.. there should be some standard procedure in MAAS for generation of custom images to be deployed on MAAS nodes

Comment: Like given in https://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/os-support.html#maas-image-builder?

Comment: yes...but it is very concise...it should have been more explanatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roughly you're looking for the maas-image-builder.  You can modify the kickstart config file which allows you to specify custom packages.

Note, normally things like PostgreSQL would be something you'd use a config management system afterwards to install.  E.g. your custom image would include say standard CIS security requirements, or perhaps any other BASE system defaults.

See:

- https://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/os-support.html
- http://www.travnewmatic.com/2015/02/ubuntu-maas-maas-image-builder-centos-6.html

For more info.  This is a moderately technical challenge to get working.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use BOMSI as a reference. BOMSI creates custom kickstarted ISO files for installing OpenStack, but you can also create a plain CentOS machine.
As simple as:

> ./bomsi-iso.sh --no_firstrun

If you are dealing with MaaS you will probably find it quite simple to hack the gen_ks.sh file to generate kickstart files for your needs.

You can find those scripts at:
https://github.com/julenl/BOMSI/